# HttpRequest using multiple urls from array Parse.com Cloudcode

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

How can i handle multiple httpRequests using url strings from an array? Below is what I've tried so far but i receive an error each time I attempt to deploy the code to parse.

```
     Parse.Cloud.define("FetchData", function(request, response) {
                           Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
                           var urls = ["url1", "url2"]

                           return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                            //For loop below FAILS**
                             for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                            url: urls[i]
                            },

               }).then(function(httpResponse) {
         //Handle Json here                                
response.success("Success"); 
    },
       function (error) {

response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        });
     });
```

Comment: Shouldn't this: `for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                                url: urls[i]
                                },` be: `for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                                return {url: urls[i]}
                                },` or something of the sort? your code doesnt make much sense in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cloud.httpRequest` returns a promise to make the request.  Call it in a loop, collecting those promises, then create a new promise using `Promise.when()` which is fulfilled when all of the http request promises are fulfilled:

```
var _ = require("underscore"); //so we can map over an array
var urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

Parse.Cloud.define("FetchData", function(request, response) {
    var promises = _.map(urls, function(url) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url });
    });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        response.success(_.toArray(arguments)); 
    }, function (error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where exactly should the loop be placed? Within the `httpResponse` function or `httpRequest`

Comment: It works where I suggest it.  (`map` loops over the urls).  The idea is to make the requests in a loop, keep the promises generated by that loop, then run them together.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense, thanks. Unfortunately, i receive an error each time i run it. Here's a screenshot of the [error message](http://imgur.com/i4Td7s0)

Comment: That looks like an error downstream from this code running successfully.  I'd wager all those [object, object] things are http responses

Comment: I changed `response.success("Success")` to  `response.success(response);` (to retrieve the `json` and parse it using swift). Could that be the issue?

Comment: That's definitely the right way to get results back to the client.

Comment: @kye - i got confused by indentation and left out the key point from the code.  please see edit (and accept my apology for the confusion).  map produces the array of promises, and Promise.when (which was missing) runs them.

Comment: That's okay and apology accepted, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I still receive the same error.

Comment: Can we look at the code around main.js line 39?  Please post the complete function and indicate which line is 39.

Comment: @kye - perhaps finally, with the help of Félix Gagnon-Grenier, we've got a solution.  please give it shot.

Comment: Thanks @FélixGagnon-Grenier.

Comment: @kye Then, please let the *unworking* code in your question. It have more chances to actually help someone else if your question doesn't feature already working code :). Also it is generally frowned upon to edit your question directly with the code in the answers. Smells of help vampirism.